# Displaying ziggy packeg wrong

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, ziggy

I installed the package tightenco/ziggy, set it up as in the documentation, everything works.
But the template displays the entire list of addresses as in the screenshot
Please tell me where I went wrong

```
<head>
        @routes
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body>
        @inertia
    </body>

<Link :href="route('listing.show', listing.id)">
            <listingAddress :listing="listing" />
        </Link>

app.js
import { ZiggyVue } from 'ziggy'
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';
```

vite.config

```
.use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)

    resolve: {
    alias: {
        ziggy: path.resolve('/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js')
    },
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [documentation](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy)  you can exclude certain routes or include the route you want to expose to the client .

> Ziggy supports filtering the routes it makes available to your JavaScript, which is great if you have certain routes that you don't want to be included and visible in the source of the response sent back to clients. Filtering routes is optional—by default, Ziggy includes all your application's named routes.
>
> To set up basic route filtering, create a config file in your Laravel
> app at config/ziggy.php and define either an only or except setting as
> an array of route name patterns.

```
// config/ziggy.php

return [
    'except' => ['_debugbar.*', '_ignition.*',],
];
```